# error showing while creating a debian file from electronjs project

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I am getting the below error while making deb file of electronjs

```
  Error: could not find the Electron app binary at "dist/app-linux-x64/koriwallet". You may need to re-bundle the app using Electron Packager's "executableName" option.
```

My package.json file is 
       {
        "name": "wallet",
             "version": "1.0.0",
           "description": "wallet",
               "main": "src/main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-packager . myapp",
    "pack": "electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "electron-builder",
    "deb64": "electron-installer-debian --src dist/app-linux-x64/ --dest dist/installers/ --arch amd64"
  },
  "author": "wallet",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "asar": "^2.0.1",
    "electron": "^5.0.6",
    "electron-builder": "^21.1.1",
    "electron-installer-debian": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-packager": "^14.0.2"
  },
  "electronPackagerConfig": {
    "packageManager": "npm",
    "executableName": "kori"
    },
  "build": {
    "appId": "wallet",
    "linux": {
      "category": "wallet"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookies": "^0.7.3",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dpkg": "^1.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jstorage": "^0.4.8"
  }
}

Answer (score 3):

My 2 cents.  I'm making an Fedora 30 rpm and got:

An unhandled error has occurred inside Forge:
An error occured while making for target: rpm
could not find the Electron app binary at "/home/ajm/Documents/Projects/sunstealer.ets/out/sunstealer.ets product-linux-x64/sunstealer.ets". You may need to re-bundle the app using Electron Packager's "executableName" option.
Error: could not find the Electron app binary at "/home/ajm/Documents/Projects/sunstealer.ets/out/sunstealer.ets product-linux-x64/sunstealer.ets". You may need to re-bundle the app using Electron Packager's "executableName" option.
    at error.wrapError (/home/ajm/Documents/Projects/sunstealer.ets/node_modules/electron-installer-common/src/installer.js:145:15)

Fix was update package.json from

"name": "sunstealer.ets",
  "productName": "sunstealer.ets product",

to:

"name": "sunstealer.ets",
  "productName": "sunstealer.ets",

i.e. same value.  Then npm run make with:

```
"forge": {
  "packagerConfig": {},
  "makers": [
    {
      "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
      "config": {
        "certificateFile": "./certs/adam_mauger.pfx",
        "certificatePassword": "REDACTED"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "@electron-forge/maker-dmg",
      "config": {
        "format": "ULFO"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
      "config": {
      }
    },
```

created sunstealer.ets-1.0.0-1.x86_64.rpm.  Hope that helps.

Comment: thank you for the solution. mine is renamed `packagerConfig.name` and `packagerConfig.executableName` to the same value as `name` in package.json :)

Answer (score 0):

my 5 cents)
so, launch npm from root folder. there exist node_modules.
app stored in root/src. there exist node_modules.
and in root and in root/src have package.json
check root/src/package.json file. maybe there parameter "name" have default value in lowercase

Answer (score -1):

I also experienced this error.
I posted how to fix the error after a lot of trial and error.

https://it-jm.tistory.com/187